# Encrypt file using AxCrypt in java

Tags: java, command-line

I want to encrypt the text file using AxCrypt. I did it through cmd but I want it from the Java program. The following 4 commands I've used in cmd.

1: location of axcrypt software directory
2: axcrypt command (which will be executed for encrypting the file)
3: import file location (file to encrypt)
4: export file location (encrypted file directory)

Here is my code:

```
public class TestCode {
    
    String axcryptLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Axantum\\AxCrypt";
    String axcryptCommand = "AxCrypt.exe -e -k \"X2U4qPtdMTMZ K63D ABnS 3gO2 PHFL XKJ/ +UsZ /QuG yp5s X78k 2wH=\" -z";  
    String fileImportLocation = "E:\\ImportExport\\firstcheck.txt";
    String fileExportLocation = "E:\\ImportExport\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Waseem You said 'clicks the button'. What button?

Comment: @rzwitserloot ok forgot the button, just run it from main method

Answer (score 0):

You need the ProcessBuilder class. It's a bit tricky to use - for example, you should replace `axcryptCommand` with a list of arguments (because splitting on space but not on quotes - that's bash/cmd.exe stuff). The command itself should be an absolute path, as well.

[Here is a tutorial on ProcessBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-processbuilder-api).

NB: Note that it is not particularly complicated to encrypt stuff in java code, without having to rely on windows-only executables. A search on the web should find you loads of tutorials on how to do this, though, as is usual with crypto, you'll probably mess something up. Such is the nature of doing a task where failure cannot be tested for.

Comment: It is a requirement to encrypt the file only in AxCrypt software.

Comment: after analyzing the given URL, still I don't know how to start.

Comment: Time to [start here](https://dev.java/learn/) then.